# Typescript - replace value in an array object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Tried two ways to get partial summary within each array object, but failed.

```
var arr = [
  { "value": 10, "newBalance": 0 },
  { "value": -10, "newBalance": 0 },
  { "value": 15, "newBalance": 0 },
];

 let total = 0;
 for (let i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
    total = total + arr[i].value;

    arr.map( item => { item.newBalance = total; return item; });
    // update all newBalance values with the last total value

    arr.map(item => item.newBalance != 0 ? { ...item, newBalance: total } : item);
    // doesn't update newBalance
}
console.log(arr);
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: First thing "wrong" as that you're using `map()` but not doing anything with the output.  You might as well use a `forEach()`.  Maybe you think `map()` reassigns the returned value to the original array?  But it doesn't, it [creates a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Ok I see, I avoided forEach because I need to use i (index) later.

Comment: I'm not talking about your `for` loop.  I'm saying that you are using `map()` for no reason; it does not assign its output to the input array; you might as well use `forEach()`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbEvdN).  This has the same behavior as yours, for the same reason.  Only `item.newBalance = total` does anything to `arr`'s elements; everything else is completely discarded.  Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done cleanly in a single loop with reduce. Note this returns a new array, it won't mutate the original. But you can always reassign `arr` to the new one if you want.

With `reduce` you can access the current accumulation which is very useful here as you can get the previous rolling value to build on for each item.

```
const arrayWithSummary = arr.reduce((summary, currentLineItem, index) => {
    return [...summary, { ...currentLineItem, newBalance: currentLineItem.value + (summary?.[index - 1]?.newBalance ?? 0)}]
}, [])
```

The result is in `arrayWithSummary`.

[image]

Comment: With this arr.reduce() function Will I still be able to insert easily rows witin the array with push() ?

Comment: Yep that will work. Reduce allows you to return an array of a different length, unlike map.

Comment: (id need to know more about the scenario where you add rows to help more)

Comment: Just an array where you can add sub summaries like  subtotal of some lines having some criterias.

Comment: Yeh that will be fine. basically all the logic would be inside the reduce callback

Comment: Here is an example of objects { name: "dd", "value": 30, "newBalance": 0 }, e.g. I would like to make "value" sub total of all objects having name: "dd" how can I ashieve that with Reduce() ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251970/discussion-between-sami-l-and-adsy).